# Spring Cache: не работает

Tags: java, spring-cache

Я подключил к проекту кэширование через `Spring Cache`.
Сначала я добавил аннотацию:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MultiSelectJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableCaching    //Spring Cache
public class Application {
```

Потом создал бин:

```
@Bean("authCacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager() {
        @Override
        protected Cache createConcurrentMapCache(String name) {
            return new ConcurrentMapCache(
                    name,
                    CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).build().asMap(),
                    false
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Я задал в бине время жизни кэша (1 день).
Далее, я повесил аннотацию над нужным методом:

```
@Cacheable(value = "ldap", key = "#username")
public Authentication authenticateByLdap(String username, String password, User userDetails) {
```

Как я понял, при попытке повторно аутентифицироваться с совпадающим параметром `username` метод должен был вернуть закешированные данные. Но данные приложение по-прежнему входит в метод (это видно по логам).

Подскажите, что не так?